# Download image from firebase react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I tried so many method to download image from firebase but download URL is nor working as what i expected, Its open the image in new tab.

The firebase function:

```
export async function addMedia(location: "initial" | "prep" | "merge" | "sribe" | "other", file: string) {

    let fileName = uuidv4();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/${location}/${fileName}`);

    let downloadLink = "";

    await uploadString(storageRef, file, "data_url").then(async (snapshot) => {
        await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((link: any) => {
            downloadLink = link;
        })
    })

   return downloadLink;
```

I'm using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) dependencies for my download purpose its working fine.

File download function:

```
const downloadImage = (url: any, name: any) => {
  console.log(url, name, "image details");
  FileSaver.saveAs(url,name);
}
```

The fire base URL im getting from firebase function:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/scribe-it-dev-5eed1.appspot.com/o/initial%2F1988-43ce-b927?alt=media&token=cdb01f22-7d9d-4aaf-adc8-323737fd7b1d

When i press download i get below result :

[Open in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBuAK.png)

Comment: [1] If you as a user are seeing the image file from the download URL anyway, why are you not able to just right click and download it manually? Also, perhaps look into [zipping the files then downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563883/can-i-zip-files-in-firebase-storage-via-firebase-cloud-functions) - this may solve the issue of opening in browser

Comment: [2] Most image URL's auto open in a view. You could solve this in html5 by adding the "download" tag, but I'm unsure of your use case so it may not apply. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)'s an article anyway.

Comment: @meropis thanks for the reply. i tried the download tag but i still get the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use base64Url to download image its working fine for me.im saving base64Url in firebase as a string

Answer (score 2):

Stop combining `await` and `then`; use one of the other, but not both.

So:

```
export async function addMedia(location: "initial" | "prep" | "merge" | "sribe" | "other", file: string) {
    let fileName = uuidv4();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/${location}/${fileName}`);

    let downloadLink = "";

    const snapshot = await uploadString(storageRef, file, "data_url");
    const link = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)

    return link;
}
```

Remember that you need to use `await` **or** `then` when calling this `addMedia` too, which means that you can't call it in your code that renders the UI. If you want to show the image in a component in the UI, store the download URL in the state of the component and use it from there, as shown in:

- [getDownloadURL takes some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521565/getdownloadurl-takes-some-time/70521871#70521871)
- [How can I download images from firebase storage and assign them as a prop to doc in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637671/how-can-i-download-images-from-firebase-storage-and-assign-them-as-a-prop-to-doc/60638505#60638505)
- [Loading Pictures from Firebase Storage to React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421475/loading-pictures-from-firebase-storage-to-react)

Comment: thanks for the reply .i  tired the code u suggest and i still get the same result. its still open in new tab. in Ui its showing perfectly.

Comment: The problem is not in the URL, but in how you handle the asynchronous results. Note that you didn't share how you call `addMedia` nor `downloadImage`, so I had to guess at what you did there. Did you read the links I shared about asynchronously loaded data and how to show it in a component? Does that explain why your code doesn't work?

Comment: I think the issue is download URL because if i download the image not saving as image its saving as a file.its not opening

Comment: this the firebase funtion call  `await addMedia("initial", value.base64Url).then((link) => {
                  firebaseUrl = link;

                  console.log(firebaseUrl, "firebase data set");
                }); `

Comment: the way i download image `const downloadImage = (url: any, name: any) => {
  console.log(url, name, "image details");
  FileSaver.saveAs(url, name);
};`

Comment: What Frank has said is that its to do with how you handle the asynchronous result. Read the links he's kindly supplied and it will help you.